# Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary on port 7055

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, testng

When I'm trying to run TestNg test case in Firefox version 39 using STS following error is thrown 'Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms'. Below are maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
 </dependency> 

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version> 
</dependency>  

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

I tried with latest jars 2.47 but it's throwing some error in my program. Please let us know whether i need to downgrade my firefox or any other possible solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First result for Google query "Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary on port 7055"

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7954

I personally had the same issue with Firefox v.36. For me Firefox v.33 works just fine.